# Convert a string with function calls to an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, function

I need to convert this function call to a simple array[] but it's not working for some reason.

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/onebattleman/fq192ajo/)

```
     var LongCombinedReady = $('#GeoImageLat').val(exifObject.GPSLatitude + "," + "'" + exifObject.GPSLatitudeRef + "'")

 var LatCombinedReady = exifObject.GPSLongitude + "," + "'" + exifObject.GPSLongitudeRef + "'"

     //an attemp to take the values and convert them to an array but it doesn't work. 
     var LongCombined = [LongCombinedReady];

     var LatCombined = [LatCombinedReady];
```

I've commented it all out in the fiddle also here's an image with GeoCoords if you don't have one for testing.

[Test Geotag image](http://pic.farbauti.de/geotag-example.jpg)

Basically I read the images Geotag and then convert the tag from DMS to DD so it can be used for something like Google maps.

Comment: I had to add some code to insert the link. It's up there now.

Comment: [.map](http://api.jquery.com/map) itself returns an array, [.get](http://api.jquery.com/get#get2) will also return an array, so Lat/LongCombinedReady are already arrays.

Comment: That's what I thought, but for some reason it's still returning as NaN.

Comment: What is returning NaN?

Comment: you have your DMSToDecimal function defined as `function (degrees, minutes, seconds, hemisphere)` but you dont pass it those types of arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three problems:

- you are missing an `apply` in line 49
- you are `apply`ing array with one item being a string while function you are applying to expects four parameters
- at line 43 `LongCombinedReady` is an jQuery object

Comment: Thanks! I missed that!